# JavaFX ScrollPane - Detect when scrollbar is visible?

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, scrollpane

I have a ScrollPane as below:

```
    ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
    scroller.getStyleClass().add("scroller");
    scroller.setPrefWidth(width);
    scroller.setFocusTraversable(Boolean.FALSE);
    scroller.setPannable(Boolean.TRUE);
    scroller.setFitToWidth(Boolean.TRUE);
    scroller.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
    scroller.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
    this.setCenter(scroller);

    scroller.contentProperty().addListener((observableValue, last, now) ->
    {
        ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) scroller.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");

        if (scrollBar != null)
        {
            if (scrollBar.isVisible())
            {
                log.info("Scrollbar visible, setting lower card width..");
            }
            else
            {
                log.info("Scrollbar not visible, setting default card width..");
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I've attached a listener to the content property to know when the content is set. I am trying to see if the scrollbar is visible when the content is updated. Even though I can see the scroll bar on the UI, it always goes to else part - "Scrollbar not visible".

Not sure if there is any other way to do this? Checked a lot on StackOverflow and Oracle docs - nothing solid found to suggest otherwise.

-- Adding context to the problem to better understand:

Just trying to explain what the problem is not sure if I should put it as a reply comment or edit the question, please advise and will change it:

So I have this view that brings up records from Firebase that need to be loaded on the TilePane that is hosted in ScrollPane which goes into the Center of the BorderPane.

The time by which I get the response from the Firebase is unpredictable as its async. So the UI gets loaded up with the empty TilePane and then the async call goes to fetch data. When the data is available, I need to prepare Cards (which is HBox) but the number of columns is fixed. So have to adjust the width of the cards to keep the gap (16px) and padding (16px) consistent on the TilePane at the same time maintain 5 columns. The width of each card needs to be recalculated based on the fact that whether or not there is a scrollbar on the display. Because if the scrollbar is displayed it takes some space and the TilePane will down it to 4 columns leaving a lot of empty space. Happy to explain further if this is not clear.

Comment: why? which problem do you want to solve depending on the visibility? [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra - Just updated the question with the context. Thank you.

Comment: If you really need to work out whether a scroll pane is visible,  the most robust way is probably via a custom scroll pane skin with an API to indicate when a scrollbar is visible, but that is likely non-trivial and not easy.

Comment: It is almost always better to edit the question to add extra info rather than posting in comments, you did the right thing there . . .

Comment: @jewelsea - I am not that expert in JavaFX and this is kind of the requirement as I can't change the time by which Firebase responds or the constraints on number of columns on the TilePane and at the same time maintain nicely, evenly spread cards with same padding and gap.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to know if the scroll bar is visible for this purpose. Since you have `setFitWidth(true)`, the width of the content will be forced to be the width of the scroll pane, less the space taken up by the scroll bar if it's visible. So instead of managing the layout of the content yourself (which is always a mistake), just make the content use an appropriate layout pane which resizes its own content accordingly.

Comment: *"I need to prepare Cards (which is HBox) but the number of columns is fixed. So have to adjust the width of the cards to keep the gap (16px) and padding (16px) consistent on the TilePane at the same time maintain 5 columns."* I don't follow all this, but it sounds like a `GridPane` would work, for example.

Comment: @James_D I am using HBox for the cards, the TilePane has a gap of 16 and padding of 16. Not sure what else should I use as the container instead of TilePane to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a `GridPane`. You can use column constraints to set each column to `20%` width, you can use `hgap` to specify a gap between them. If you are managing the sizes of any components yourself, you're simply doing this wrong.

Comment: Please understand that this was an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @jewelsea, thanks for letting me know about the xy problem. This is the first time I came to know about it.. and it completly makes sense !!

Comment: Thanks, everyone. GridPane did the job. All the issues are solved. No need to observe any listeners/scrollbars. All good. Thanks a heap! @James_D - I used column constraints for each column with 20% width. Updating Answer.

Comment: you can't know who downvoted - please stop spreading your assumptions ;) Anyway: xy questions are rarely helpful to anybody except the asker - actually there is no relation between the question and your own answer (the other answer is severely suboptimal due to the question being suboptimal), so what would anybody researching a problem would look for? But then, it's mute to debate - keep learning and apply what you learned (including to provide a [mcve] in your next question .. which for some reason you insisted not doing so far)

Comment: one last comment to a critical misconception in your code snippet: mostly it's _wrong_ to listen to one property (here: content) and let the listener do something based on  the value of a sibling property (here: scrollbar visibility). It's okay _only_ if those two properties are completely orthogonal to each other (which typically you can't know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James_D said, used GridPane and it worked without any listeners:

```
    GridPane cards = new GridPane();
    cards.setVgap(16);
    cards.setHgap(16);

    cards.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    cards.setPadding(new Insets(16));

    ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
    constraints.setPercentWidth(20);
    constraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    constraints.setFillWidth(Boolean.TRUE);

    cards.getColumnConstraints().addAll(constraints, constraints, constraints, constraints, constraints);
```

I have 5 columns, so 5 times constraints. Worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to follow the suggestions given in the comments. It is all about choosing the correct layout.

The purpose of me answering this question is, in future, if someone comes across this question for dealing with scroll bar visibility, they will atleast know a way to get that (**in JavaFX 8**).

One way to check for the scrollbar visiblity is to register the appropriate scrollbar on layoutChildren and add a listener to its visilble property. Something like...

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane() {
    ScrollBar vertical;

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();
        if (vertical == null) {
            vertical = (ScrollBar) lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
            vertical.visibleProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> updateContent(val));
            updateContent(vertical.isVisible());
        }
    }
};
```

The `updateContent(visible)` method is stuff you want to do when the visibility gets updated.

A complete working demo is as below.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollPaneScrollBarVisibility_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.setTitle("ScrollBar visibility");
        stage.show();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane() {
            ScrollBar vertical;

            @Override
            protected void layoutChildren() {
                super.layoutChildren();
                if (vertical == null) {
                    vertical = (ScrollBar) lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
                    vertical.visibleProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> updateContent(val));
                    updateContent(vertical.isVisible());
                }
            }
        };
        scrollPane.setContent(getContent());
        borderPane.setCenter(scrollPane);
    }

    private void updateContent(boolean scrollBarVisible) {
        System.out.println("Vertical scroll bar visible :: " + scrollBarVisible);
    }

    private VBox getContent() {
        VBox labels = new VBox();
        labels.setSpacing(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            labels.getChildren().add(new Label("X " + i));
        }
        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setOnAction(e -> labels.getChildren().add(new Label("Text")));
        Button remove = new Button("Remove");
        remove.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!labels.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
                labels.getChildren().remove(labels.getChildren().size() - 1);
            }
        });
        HBox buttons = new HBox(add, remove);
        buttons.setSpacing(15);

        VBox content = new VBox(buttons, labels);
        content.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        content.setSpacing(15);
        return content;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to go hacky - skin has api to access the bars if we _really_ want them..

Comment: Yeah..you are right.. :) I always think in the context of JavaFX 8.

Comment: well, you are doing it not quite correctly- even for the extremely outdated fx8 ;) Managing the scrollBar is and was the task of the skin - replace it with a custom skin if needed. Yeaahh, I know it's private api pre-9, so it boils down to choose between two evils :) btw: keeping a reference to a looked-up child is whacky, will break on changing the skin. Which might appear far-fetched, but some skin providers do it f.i. when switching the theme.